# How do I make an if statement for my imageview rotation in touchesMoved?

Tags: ios, swift, touchesmoved

I have this circle that the user can rotate 360 in either direction with their finger like a knob. What I would like to add is an `if` statement to the code so that I could handle other actions when the user turns the knob to the right and left. How would I do that? Here is the code I have and if you need more info let me know.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    if touch!.view === knob {

        let position = touch!.locationInView(self.view)
        let target = leftTurnTable.center
        let angle = atan2(target.y-position.y, target.x-position.x)
        knob.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What type of actions or checks do you need?

Comment: You know how you can lower the volume on a stero knob when going to the left and higher going to the right. I need an if statement so I could add my action to the left and right.

Comment: In other words, you want code to determine which direction the user is turning the knob? Keep track of the previous angle and then compare to the new angle.

Comment: How would I do that? @rmaddy

Comment: Use an instance variable to store the angle.

Comment: So I could do let turnToLeft = angle and then make an if statement depending on what direction it goes?

Comment: You could use a `switch` statement with `angle` as the variable you're concerned with. From there, you could specify cases based on angles. Without knowing more about how important angles are to what you're doing, I can't really answer your question in detail, but a switch is something to consider.

Comment: Its basically like a turntable where the user can rotate to the left and right 360.@AdrianB